# How to execute SQL statements on a dataset which didn't come from a database?

Tags: delphi, dataset, delphi-xe2

Suppose I have an application which fetches a custom XML packet from the server which represents a dataset. Then, suppose I wish to execute a SQL statement on that data via a dataset. What can I use to do this? I don't need to know the code necessarily, but just what to use to make this possible and a general explanation of how.

For example, I may fetch a list of customers in XML format from the server. Then, I can use any third-party parser to dump that XML data into some client dataset. Then, execute a query on that dataset, for example `select * from customers where ZipCode = '12345'` without fetching this data from the server again.

XML is not the only limitation, that's just an example. I might want to do the same to some application settings loaded from an INI file. Either way, the concept is that the original source of the data is unknown.

Whether the dataset stores its temporary data in the memory or on the disk doesn't matter, but it would be excellent if it could keep it in the disk.

Comment: So, you're looking for a in-memory database which will somehow (magically :-) transform XML, INI and whatever else data (*the original source of the data is unknown*) into a table structures filled with data, so you'll be able to query them ?

Comment: @TLama That is correct. Doesn't matter the original source, as long as it's placed in a temporary data structure and can be queried.

Comment: @Jerry When you've written it put it on github.com I'd love to use it also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TXQuery (http://code.google.com/p/txquery/) is a component that provides a local SQL engine for executing SQL queries against one or more TDataSets.  The only issues I have had with it is updating data via a TDBGrid of a query joining multiple tables (TDataSets) - specifically which table is being updated.

AnyDac v6 (now FireDac) also has a local SQL engine.  http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/docu/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=Local_SQL.html

Edit:  For the example SQL in your question, because it only involves a single table, you do this with just a Filter on the datatset.  For example

```
ADataSet.Filtered := False;
ADataSet.Filter := 'ZipCode=' + QuotedStr('12345');
ADataSet.Filtered := True;
```

Answer (score 4):

Such a feature can be done using a local database. You just insert the `TDataSet` result into a local in-memory (or file-based) stand-alone database, then you can use regular SQL queries on it, including JOIN.

You can for instance use [SQLite3](http://www.sqlite.org/), or the free edition of [NexusDB](http://www.nexusdb.com/support/index.php?q=FreeEmbedded).

*NexusDB embedded* has the benefit of being a native Delphi database, so stick to the `DB.pas TDataSet` paradigm.

Another option is to use the so-called [Virtual Table mechanism of SQLite3](http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html), which allows to expose any data (even from TDataSet, XML, JSON or in-memory objects) to the SQLite3 engine, just as regular tables. Then you can run SQL statements on those "virtual" tables, including JOINs. With this approach, you do not require to *INSERT* the data into regular tables, but the data remain in their original form. Of course, you will miss some performance features like indexes, which should be handled on the virtual table provider side. We use this feature as the database core of our [mORMot ORM/SOA framework](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/08/07/SQLite3-powered,-not-SQLite3-limited), and this is pretty powerful.

Answer (score 2):

The general process that you want to perform is complicated by the difference in data representation. SQL data is stored in tables made up of distinguishable records.  XML is a structured representation of data, but in tree form rather than table/row form.

Each of these data forms may be qualified by a schema that provides a context for the data.

You have two general paths that you can follow:

1. Take the XML, and based on the schema insert it into a set of interlinked tables, then perform the SQL query. - if you have the schema, you can use code generators to make a parser, and then based ont the parse tree, you can insert into a local db with tables constructed on the fly.  You can set up my SQL pretty easily from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/installing.html and then in your version of delphi make a connection to the database, first fill it in, then query.  This would satisfy your desire to have the data stored on the disk.  unless you purge the tables when done, the data are still available in the local machine db.

This seems like more work than:

1. Use Xpath or Xquery and work directly on the XML.  For this, a package like saxon in your favorite environment, or expat in python would work nicely.

Let me know if either of these paths seems as if it may be fruitful.

Comment: There are no official schemas involved. I would consider this answer if I was mentioning that my XML format was some standard format, but I'm only using XML as an example of what the data source *might* be. I'm mentioning "Custom XML"

Comment: I'm OK with you not considering this an answer. If you would like to pursue this, then I would like to refine the acceptable scope of useable answeres.  If the format that you receive the data in is just XML-like, then mapping the XML to the SQL database may not be part of your desired answer.  That would take us closer to path 2, but if the query has to be in SQL, for path 1, a local install of mysql [link] (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/installing.html) might be the next link to follow toward an answer.

Comment: @ElderDelp, why MySQL, if there are lightweight in-memory databases available for Delphi ?

Comment: I'm aiming to ignore any standard database engine such as SQL Server or MySQL or anything. I'm sure such things are already available in Delphi, just I'm seeking for exactly what.

Comment: @TLama, given that there is a solution inside Delphi, then the question is if this can be made persistent beyond the running of the program.